# Python numerical integration artificially satellites

Tags: python, integration, astronomy

Where can I find real data for Earth artificial satellites, and how can I use methods of numerical integration to get some 'useful' results?

I think if I can find some velocity of satellite and integrate them, I can get coordinates. Or if you have some better idea, I will like to hear what I can do. Also, I will like to do this in Python.

Comment: scrape this website: http://www.n2yo.com/?  check for the lat, long (x0, y0) and predict new coordinates based on the current velocity and the time delta?

Comment: see [realistic n-body solar system simulation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28020934/2521214) satelites use a bit different orbital parameters then planets,comets etc  so search NASA.gov sites for equations/explanations

Comment: To help narrow your question focus, I have removed the “pyephem” tag since pyephem — like most astronomy libraries — does no numerical integration.

Comment: Is there a reason for numerical integration to obtain position? Using two line elements in software like pyephem is much simpler and more accurate than what you're likely to achieve.